# Why the text isn't white?

Tags: html, css

Here is the source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <title>White</title>
   <style>
body {
   background-color: black;
}
.quadrant-legend {
    position: absolute;
    left    :  28px;
    width   : 288px;
    height  :  62px;
}
.quadrant-legend-img {
    position: absolute;
    top     : 0;
    left    : 0;
    z-index : 3;
}
.quadrant-legend-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top     :  6px;
    right   : 34px;
    z-index : 3;
}
.quadrant-legend-text {
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-top : 16px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size  : 26px;
    color      : white;
    z-index    : 4;
}
#quadrant-legend-asset {
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 4;
}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="quadrant-legend-asset" class="quadrant-legend">
      <img class="quadrant-legend-img" src="images/quadrant-bg.svg" />
      <img class="quadrant-legend-btn" src="images/quadrant-asset-btn.svg" />
      <p class="quadrant-legend-text">lightblue text</p>
   </div>
   <p class="quadrant-legend-text">white text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result, as displayed by Firefox or Chrome

[image: White becomes lightblue]

**The question is: Why white text becomes lightblue?**

*Note:* I have added some `z-index` CSS directives without any effect.

Comment: try adding `!important`

Comment: Recommending `!important` is a bad idea. You should always use more specific selectors before resorting to `!important`.

Comment: Using the code you have provided, the text _is_ white: https://jsfiddle.net/z5h83h20/

Comment: Try to add `position: relative` to `.quadrant-legend-text`, the `z-index` applies only to *positioned* elements.

Comment: @aghidini: Beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `z-index` property applies only to *positioned* elements (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)). Probably your `images/quadrant-bg.svg` image is partially transparent and is displayed on top of the text.

Add `position: relative` to the `.quadrant-legend-text` selector and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is a specificity issue, so try adding the parent to the rule.

plus `z-index` will **only** work in `position`ed elements, but I'm pretty sure you won't need that here in this specific case

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.quadrant-legend {
  position: absolute;
  left: 28px;
  width: 288px;
  height: 62px;
}
.quadrant-legend-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.quadrant-legend-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 34px;
  z-index: 3;
}
#quadrant-legend-asset .quadrant-legend-text {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute
}
#quadrant-legend-asset {
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id="quadrant-legend-asset" class="quadrant-legend">
  <img class="quadrant-legend-img" src="images/quadrant-bg.svg" />
  <img class="quadrant-legend-btn" src="images/quadrant-asset-btn.svg" />
  <p class="quadrant-legend-text">lightblue text</p>
</div>
<p class="quadrant-legend-text">white text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.quadrant-legend-img` and `.quadrant-legend-btn` are `position:absolute`, but `.quadrant-legend-text` has no `position` attribute. This means that the `z-index` on that `.quadrant-legend-text` will not apply, making the text appear behind the `.quadrant-legend-img`, which is your `images/quadrant-bg.svg`, which I assume is a semi-transparent blue rectangle?

You shouldn't be using so much `position:absolute` for your basic layout features - consider using `float: right` for the `.quadrant-legend-btn` and removing the `.quadrant-legend-img` in favour of a `background-image` on `.quadrant-legend-asset`.

Comment: background-image is not a good idea since we must specify the size of the box when I prefer taking the size from the svg itself.

Comment: @Aubin As you wish, in that case just add `position:relative` to the `p` to allow `z-index` to apply.

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
.quadrant-legend-text p {
    color : #fff;
}
```